# jquery - $(this).... inside $.post

Tags: jquery

Here's my code

```
$("#idselectB").click(function() {
    var id = $("#idselectB option:selected").text();
    $.post('elegir.php', {'id': id}, function (data) {
         $(this).closest(':input').val(data);
    });
});
```

When I click in a dropdown list I get the value selected. Then I send the value to elegir.php and it returns me a string. Finally I want to insert this string to the closest input.

If I do `alert($(this).closest(':input').val(data));` this returns me: `[object Object]`

¿How can I insert the returned value where I want?

I have a lot of input texts, so I need `closest()`

Comment: Paste the html so we can tell if you are targeting the desired element..

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the reference to a clicked element somewhere:

```
$("#idselectB").click(function() {
    var id = $("#idselectB option:selected").text(),
        that = this; // this is a reference to a clicked object

    $.post('elegir.php', {'id': id}, function (data) {
         $(that).closest(':input').val(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: ok, now i'll try it, it's the first time I see "that", what cases must i use "that" in?

Comment: @iwondernow: `this` always refer to a **current** scope. In the `$.post` callback handler it is another scope. So when you refer to `$(this)` in the callback handler - you're getting different value, not what you had a level upper. PS: There is nothing magic in `that` name, you could use any - like `foo = this` and use `foo`

Comment: ok, i've understood it perfectly, i was suspecting something like this, that "this" was being corrupted by $.post, now it works!
thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There are two commonly used approaches.

You can copy the reference from `this` into a local variable, which will be captured in the closure for the callback function so that you can use it there also:

```
$("#idselectB").click(function() {
  var id = $("#idselectB option:selected").text();
  var t = this;
  $.post('elegir.php', {'id': id}, function (data) {
     $(t).closest(':input').val(data);
  });
});
```

You can set the context of the callback function using the [`proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$("#idselectB").click(function() {
  var id = $("#idselectB option:selected").text();
  $.post('elegir.php', {'id': id}, $.proxy(function (data) {
     $(this).closest(':input').val(data);
  }, this));
});
```